How to mock the database?
I have this spring boot application from the starter web app.
spring.application.name=demo
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Following are the dependencies I have included.
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docker-compose'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
testImplementation group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: '3.26.3'

All I'm doing is handles a POST request from /reader endpoint and using JpaRepository<Reader, Long>.save() function to save the record.
Everything works as expected when running with ./gradlew bootRun except the test. I tried many tutorials using various different annotations to no luck.
From what I understand, spring boot creates the DB connection at the start of the application. So, for testing how do I simply disable the DB configuration and mock the repository to return a mocked object?
Following fails with org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused Error.
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ReaderControllerTest {
  @LocalServerPort
  private int port;

  @Mock
  private ReaderRepository readerRepository;

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  void createUserTest() throws Exception {
    var newReader = new Reader();
    newReader.setName("user");
    newReader.setEmail("user@email.com");

    Mockito.when(readerRepository.save(null)).thenReturn(newReader);

    mockMvc
        .perform(
            post("http://localhost:" + port + "/user").contentType("application/json").content("{\"name\": \"test\"}"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
}


Some hypothesis, relying on the code you posted above.
Since you are using @SpringBootTest, the test runs all the context (also the database). If you want to test just the controller and mock all the dependent beans, you can try to use the @WebMvcTest(ReaderController.class) annotation instead. Using this, you can also avoid to inject the local server port and you can give the post method the relative path starting with "/user", without  the absolute prefix.
There are two more thins: perhaps you have to use a @MockBean annotation instead of @Mock to make the mocked ReaderRepository to be injected in the controller, and provide any() or any(Reader.class) as an argument of the readerRepository.save() mocked method.
